# Using keyboard input to login in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a button, when clicked goes to the next route/page in Angular.
Is there a way we can use the same button but instead of clicking it sometimes give the user to enter a secret passphrase on the keyboard to navigate to the next page.
Example: if a user types "nextpage" he should go to the next page.

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/us-keyboard-to-go) code for page routing

HTML:

```
<button (click)=goToNextPage()>Click me or type the passphrase</button>
```

TS:

```
goToNextPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/newPage'], { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor() {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', this.addkey);
}

typed = '';

addkey = event =>  {
  this.typed += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  if (this.typed.endsWith('NEXTPAGE')) {
    this.goToNextPage();
  }
};

ngOnDestroy() {
  document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.addkey);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/us-keyboard-to-go-7kmsl7?file=src/app/checkin/checkin.component.ts

You could put in a test for backspace to remove the last character if you want.